# How to combine ARRAYFORMULA and COUNTIF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, array-formulas

I'm new to Google Sheets.
I try to count values in column A using ArrayFormula and CountIf, but the result is not I want.

I try in each row with this

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

so each row will count values from A2 until the row appears.

But if I try with arrayformula, the result is different

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF($A$2:A,A2:A))
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

This is [my spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DYJ7PNvBYg-DAHS7n5H2_NoeOtpdXaCvZp_Uv5KJEK4/edit?usp=sharing)

Please Help me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), ))
```

[image: 0]